# How to replace value with comma while using update query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
$data = array(
             'recruiter_id'=>REPLACE(recruiter_id,201812101140,'')
         );
$where = "jid='".$this->input->post('jid')."'";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('job_registration',$data);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

I have recruiter ids like `2018121011430, 201812101140, 201812101141`. Now, I want to remove `201812101140` using an update query. Here is my query but it doesn't work. How can I remove `201812101140` from the column `recruiter_id`?

Comment: _Don't_ try to do this!  _Normalize_ your data, and change your table structure so that a single `recruiter_id` appears on each record.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  please look at my query once this query show me ` 0 rows affected`

Comment: You are completely ignoring everything I said in my comment, therefore I won't comment further.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad!

Answer (score 0):

In mysql replace function syntax is `REPLACE(field_name,string_to_find, string_to_replace)`.

You have to replace comma with space. Your query should look like this.

```
UPDATE job_registration SET recruiter_id=replace(recruiter_id,',','') WHERE job_id='jid1205161020' and recruiter_id like '%20181130070940%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array(
    'recruiter_id' => ''
);
$this->db->where('jid', $this->input->post('jid'));
$this->db->where('recruiter_id', 201812101140);
$this->db->update('job_registration', $data);
```

Comment: @Bruce Can you post an example row which you would want to replace

Comment: Please add some explanation - what do you want to tell us with your source code?